# REDCap API import records in Android

Tags: android, api, apache, http, redcap

I'm trying to use the REDCap API to import records using an Android app. How do I make a button in an activity run the code below when clicked in order upload the data into REDCap? If there is another way to code this, that would be just as helpful. I basically want to send the data in the JSON object into REDCap using their API token and URL that's already given to me.

```
package com.example.maciej.fuglmeyer;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;


public class MyClass
{
    private final HttpPost post;
    private final HttpClient client;
    private int respCode;
    private BufferedReader reader;
    private final StringBuffer result;
    private String line;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public MyClass(final Config c)
    {
        JSONObject record = new JSONObject();
        record.put("record_id", "3");
        record.put("first_name", "First");
        record.put("last_name", "Last");
        record.put("address", "123 Cherry Lane\nNashville, TN 37015");
        record.put("telephone", "(615) 255-4000");
        record.put("email", "first.last@gmail.com");
        record.put("dob", "1972-08-10");
        record.put("age", "43");
        record.put("ethnicity", "1");
        record.put("race", "4");
        record.put("sex", "1");
        record.put("height", "180");
        record.put("weight", "105");
        record.put("bmi", "31.4");
        record.put("comments", "comments go here");
        record.put("demographics_complete", "2");

        JSONArray data = new JSONArray();
        data.add(record);

        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("token", "123423412342134"));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("content", "record"));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("format", "json"));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("type", "flat"));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("data", data.toJSONString()));

        post = new HttpPost("URLGOESHERE.com");
        post.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

        try
        {
            post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
        }
        catch (final Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        result = new StringBuffer();
        client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
        respCode = -1;
        reader = null;
        line = null;
    }

    public void doPost()
    {
        HttpResponse resp = null;

        try
        {
            resp = client.execute(post);
        }
        catch (final Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if(resp != null)
        {
            respCode = resp.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

            try
            {
                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(resp.getEntity().getContent()));
            }
            catch (final Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        if(reader != null)
        {
            try
            {
                while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    result.append(line);
                }
            }
            catch (final Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        System.out.println("respCode: " + respCode);
        System.out.println("result: " + result.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you ask this question on the private REDCap forums?  If that was unsuccessful, ask your campus's REDCap admin for the "redcap-api-examples.zip" file that can be downloaded from http://yourredcapserver.edu/redcap/api/help/?content=examples.  There are several java examples; one resembles your code above, but has some scoping differences.

Answer (score 1):

1) Create a simple *Layout* with a *Button* and a *EditText* for the data will be uploaded:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/parent_log"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="16dp"
    android:paddingEnd="16dp"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:paddingStart="16dp"
    android:paddingTop="16dp">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/input_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Exemplo: João da Silva"
        android:inputType="textPersonName" />

     <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="CADASTRAR"
        android:id="@+id/uploadData"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:onClick="onClick" />

 </LinearLayout>
```

2) In *onClick* method on your Activity, get the data and call the Class ***Config*** and the ***ImportData*** (content in Java Examples on REDCap API)

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    String name = findViewById(R.id.input_name).getText().toString();

    Config config = new Config();

    //I have changed the constructor to send the only string that will be
    //uploaded, but you can send a context, array of strings, whatever...
    ImportRecords importRecords = new ImportRecords(config, name);
    importRecords.doPost();
}
```

3) On ImportRecords, class you posted, change the constructor (if you want) and here is an example of the code you can do

```
public class ImportRecords {
private final List<NameValuePair> params;
private final HttpPost post;
private HttpResponse resp;
private final HttpClient client;
private int respCode;
private BufferedReader reader;
private final StringBuffer result;
private String line;
private final JSONObject record;
private final JSONArray data;
private String recordID;
//private final SecureRandom random;

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public ImportRecords(final Config c, String name) {
    //Create an id. Id is the record identifier
    //For example if you want get the record in the future, you'll need that
    Random r = new Random();
    int id = r.nextInt();

    record = new JSONObject();
    record.put("record_id", id);
    record.put("first_name", name);

    data = new JSONArray();
    data.add(record);

    params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("token", c.API_TOKEN));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("content", "record"));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("format", "json"));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("type", "flat"));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("data", data.toJSONString()));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("forms", "pergunta"));

    //c.API_URL is the url found on your REDCap project - API
    post = new HttpPost(c.API_URL);
    post.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    try {
        post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
    } catch (final Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    result = new StringBuffer();
    client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
    respCode = -1;
    reader = null;
    line = null;
}
```

4) On Android, the method **Post** needs to run on background. I have created an *AsyncTask* for that

```
public void doPost() {
    new Task().execute();
}

public class Task extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
        resp = null;

        try {
            resp = client.execute(post);
        } catch (final Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }

        if (resp != null) {
            respCode = resp.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();


            try {
                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(resp.getEntity().getContent()));
            } catch (final Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return false;
            }
        }

        if (reader != null) {
            try {
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    result.append(line);
                }
            } catch (final Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return false;
            }
        }

        System.out.println("respCode: " + respCode);
        System.out.println("result: " + result.toString());
        if (respCode!=200)
            return false;
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean aBoolean) {
        super.onPostExecute(aBoolean);
        if (aBoolean)
            Log.e("RESULT","The record was sent");
        else
            Log.e("RESULT","The record was not sent");
    }
}
```